# CLLocation copy

Tags: objective-c, copy, cllocation

I've inherited this code and am trying to figure out why there's a `copy` in it.

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

i.e. is there some reason why you need to do a `deep copy` on a `CLLocation` and use `_location = [inLocation copy]` rather than just `_location = inLocation`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason on the original author's side could be the intention to **prevent strong reference from the presentation layer to the model object**  (which is the location), that could wreak havoc to the lifecycle of the model object. By copying, you get a new independent instance that matches the one in the model layer.

And it is a good practice I must say. There is no reason why anything that is presented in a"flat 2D" manner on presentation layer, should be the live model object instance. 
Of course I realise the new location instance is also a real object instance (not primitive value) but its purpose is strictly limited to "hang around" in the UI layer and die with it. 
There is this trend to un-objectify some types that were previously objects in Objective-C...and now they are structs in Swift.